# How to configure google_mobile_ads and local_auth packages in MainActivity.kt file?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to integrate the google_mobile_ads and local_auth packages into my Flutter app's MainActivity.kt file. However, I'm having trouble configuring it correctly. Can anyone provide guidance on how to set up these packages in the MainActivity.kt file?
I have already added the required dependencies for google_mobile_ads and local_auth packages in my Flutter project. I need assistance with the necessary configurations and code snippets that need to be added specifically to the MainActivity.kt file. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**NOTE:** Without FlutterFragmentActivity, no errors, but I can't use fingerprint authentication

here is the error i got:

```
e: C:\flutterprojelerim\auto_daily\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\devonesoft\app\auto_daily\MainActivity.kt: (17, 71): Unresolved reference: context

e: C:\flutterprojelerim\auto_daily\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\devonesoft\app\auto_daily\MainActivity.kt: (20, 68): Unresolved reference: context
```

My MainActivity.kt file:

```
package com.devonesoft.app.auto_daily
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

// COMPLETE: Import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine

// COMPLETE: Import io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin
import io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin
class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

        // TODO: Register the MyNativeAdFactory
        GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.registerNativeAdFactory(
                flutterEngine, "MyNativeAdFactory", MyNativeAdFactory(context))
        // TODO: Register the ListTileNativeAdFactory
        GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.registerNativeAdFactory(
                flutterEngine, "listTile", ListTileNativeAdFactory(context))
    }

    override fun cleanUpFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.cleanUpFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

        // TODO: Unregister the ListTileNativeAdFactory
        GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.unregisterNativeAdFactory(flutterEngine, "MyNativeAdFactory")
          // TODO: Unregister the ListTileNativeAdFactory
        GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.unregisterNativeAdFactory(flutterEngine, "listTile")
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding this import: `import android.content.Context`. ALso instead of passing `context`, you can try using `this` keyword. For Eg: `GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.registerNativeAdFactory(
                flutterEngine, "MyNativeAdFactory", MyNativeAdFactory(this))`

Comment: thank you very much,it happened when i used this: GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.registerNativeAdFactory( flutterEngine, "MyNativeAdFactory", MyNativeAdFactory(this))